# How to make swipejs work with responsive DOM?

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with [SwipeJS](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe), I had a DOM which is a responsive object on the page. How could I make it work with swipejs, so whenever I change window size, it change dimension to fit with the screen?

```
<div id="myDOM">
  <ul class="myDOM-wrapper">
    <li>ONE</li>
    <li>TWO</li>
    <li>THREE</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

myDOM is completely responsive.

Is there anyway to force it responsive when we change the windows size? Is media queries CSS resolved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their guidance, you are able to kill it and then generate it again.

```
window.mySwipe = Swipe(documeent.getElementById('slider'));
```

To make it responsive, after you kill it, re-generate it again. Please make sure you use % for your DOM instead of a fixed number.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   window.mySwipe.kill(); //Kill it first
   window.mySwipe = Swipe(documeent.getElementById('slider')); //It will get the new dimension of the DOM
});
```